# How to find the source of event in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

For some reason, I am having different behavior for touch and mouse interaction with my application, so I would like to know the source of event for my application.  In Javascript, I am able to find the source of event whether it's touch or mouse or pen through

```
function containerMove(evt) {
    alert(evt.pointerType);
}
```

but in TypeScript, I can't find any property like this. Can anyone help me to find the source of event in TypeScript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check evt.sourceCapabilities if firesTouchEvents true then touch device else clik

Answer (score 3):

If your event is of type [PointerEvent](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L12422) (otherwise it shouldn't have the `pointerType` property) then simply state it:

```
function containerMove(evt: PointerEvent) {
    alert(evt.pointerType);
}
```